# ASP.net Web API attribute routing with int and string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

This should be a quick one.
I have two routes:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Catalogue))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id) => Ok(_catalogueService.Get(id));
```

And

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{numberOfResults:int}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Catalogue>))]
public IHttpActionResult List(bool active, int numberOfResults) => Ok(_catalogueService.List(active, numberOfResults));
```

When I use postman to try to **List** my catalogues , I pass something like this

> /catalogues/10

And I expect it to go the the `List` method in my controller. Similarly, if I want to **Get** a catalogue, I pass something like this:

> /catalogues/AB100

My routes were working, but I recently made a change to the `List` method (I added the active bool) and now my routes are not working properly.
Both examples I gave above get captured by the `Get` method which is wrong.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: This seems like an issue waiting to happen, I would strongly recommend against using the same route based on whether the value is a string or an int.

Comment: Maybe, but what I don't understand is that we use this throughout our API and it's only this one that has a problem.

Comment: Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. Maybe not applicable right now, but let's say a catalogue ID comes through as `12345`, what would you expect your app to do now? Build for future changes like this and you're in a much safer position.

Comment: @r3plica add a default value for `active` and put it after `numberOfResults` parameter as an optional parameter. Because of the additional *required* parameter, it will not longer match the route by default because it would be expecting active to be part of the URL even if not in the route template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a default value for `active` and put it after `numberOfResults` parameter as an optional parameter.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{numberOfResults:int}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Catalogue>))]
public IHttpActionResult List(int numberOfResults, bool active = true) => //assuming active default
    Ok(_catalogueService.List(active, numberOfResults));
```

Because of the additional *required* `active` parameter, it will no longer match the original overloaded route by default because it would be expecting `active` to be part of the URL even if not in the route template.

Like

```
/catalogues/10?active=true
```

By making that parameter optional it means that it can now match the expected behavior as before with the `active` value provided to the action when omitted from the URL